# Minimal embedding of a group into the group $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I am aware this has come up recently ([[Embedding of finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27132/embedding-of-finite-groups)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27132/embedding-of-finite-groups) for example) but after searching I haven't found the particular answer I'm looking for. Suppose I know the character table and can figure out the minimal (degree) faithful representation of group G (such as a subgroup of a Frobenius group): can I then find/bound accurately the smallest m such that our group G embeds into S$_m$? It is merely my idle curiosity as to whether it is possible, but I would like to be able to give as accurate a bound on n as possible, or indeed find it. <strike>www.austms.org.au/Gazette/2008/Nov08/TechPaperSaunders.pdf seems to suggest in the first few lines that it simply **is** the degree of the min. faithful representation, but is it really that simple?</strike> Could anyone suggest anything? Thank you very much - Tom H

EDIT: Just to let everyone know I spoke further with a colleague and after reading a few books I circumvented the issue I was having, so problem solved: I now consider this question closed, in case it needs marking as such.

Comment: Certainly it is at least one _more_ than the degree of the minimal faithful representation (since any faithful permutation representation on a set of size $n$ gives rise to a faithful representation of dimension $n-1$ given by taking the free vector space then subtracting a copy of the trivial rep).

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of that, of course. Is there any way in particular to tell when you can obtain this bound and when you can't? I suppose there's no more you can do than check whether your minimal faithful representation or an equally small one is a permutation representation, is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper you mention does *not* claim that the minimal degree of a faithful representation is your $n$, it says "of a faithful *permutation* representation." It is easy to see that the other statement would be too strong: $S_3$ has an irreducible faithful 2-dimensional representation, but you certainly cannot embed $S_3$ into $S_2$. Similarly, you cannot embed a cyclic group into $S_1$.

Your question has been [asked on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48928/smallest-n-for-which-g-embeds-in-s-n), and as you can see from that discussion, it is a fairly delicate issue. You will not find a simple relationship between the minimal degree of a faithful representation and the smallest $n$, as the example of cyclic groups shows (the former is always 1, the latter can be arbitrarily large).

Comment: Ah sorry, I obviously missed 'permutation'. I did see the mathoverflow discussion, though I thought perhaps with the given advantages of a little additional knowledge it might be feasible in certain small cases. I am surprised GAP doesn't have the capabilities, though evidently it is one of those problems which is far simpler to state than it is to solve.

Answer (score 2):

The character table does not determine the minimum size of a faithful permutation representation.  For instance the two non-abelian groups of order 8 have the same character table, but the minimum sizes are 4 and 8.  (Their minimal faithful complex representations have degree 2.)

For which group are you trying to find the minimal permutation representation?

Comment: Sorry for slow response: I've been abroad in London.

The groups I am interested in were subgroups of e.g. Frobenius/permutation groups (of course there is an obvious embedding, but I was curious how to find out whether it embeds in smaller groups). I looked into a few specific cases but couldn't see anything obvious.

I'm not averse to using other methods than representations - they were a suggestion from a colleague - I just want a way better than evaluating the entire group in depth. However, as has been stated, it's far from trivial, so don't worry if there is no solution!