# Every Finite Group is Isomorphic to a Subgroup of $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How does one prove that every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of an alternating group?

Comment: firstly by trying, what have you tried?

Comment: Hint:  it suffices to show it for symmetric groups.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27132/embedding-of-finite-groups

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding of finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27132/embedding-of-finite-groups)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By Cayley's theorem every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of  $S_n $.

Then $S_n $ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_{n+2}$.  To see this,  map even permutations to themselves,  and for odd permutations map to the even permutation gotten by multiplying by the transposition  $(n+1 \ n+2) $.  It is straightforward to  check that this defines an embedding.

One can take the composition of the two embeddings:  $G\hookrightarrow S_n\hookrightarrow A_{n+2}$, where $n=|G|$.