# Any finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $A_n$ for some positive integer n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

This is a classical question in the basic group theory and I try to write down the proof :

Without loss of generality that we assume the order of $G$ is $n\in\mathbb{N}$.Then Cayley theorem says that the group $G$ can be embedded in the symmetry group $S_n$.
In other words, $G\cong\iota(G)\leq S_n\,,$ where $\iota$ is the induced embedding map from $G$ to $S_n$.

Then $S_n$ also can be embedded in $A_{n+2}$.

To this end,we define the following map $\varphi :S_n\longrightarrow A_{n+2}$ by
$$\varphi : \alpha \longmapsto \begin{cases}\alpha& ,whenever\;\;\alpha\in A_n\\{}\\
\alpha(n+1\;n+2)&,whenever\;\alpha\in S_n- A_n\end{cases}$$
Then the map $\varphi$ is well-defined monomorphism.

Henceforth,combine these two results to obtain an embedding mapping $\varphi\,\circ\iota :G\longrightarrow A_{n+2}$

we then have $G\cong\varphi(\iota(G))\leq A_{n+2}$ , so our conclusion follows.

Is there any problem for the above proof ? Any advice will appreciate it.Thanks for considering my request and patiently reading.

I take note under the line and everybody can ignore it since there is some tedious,or, any comment will appreciate it.

$\rule{18cm}{2pt}$

*$\varphi$ is well-defined :*

For each $\alpha,\beta\in S_n$ with $\alpha=\beta$.

(i): If $\alpha,\beta\in A_n$,then $\varphi(\alpha)=\alpha=\beta=\varphi(\beta)$

(ii): If $\alpha,\beta\in S_n -A_n$,then $\varphi(\alpha)=\alpha(n+1\;n+2)=\beta(n+1\;n+2)=\varphi(\beta)$

*$\varphi$ is a group homomorphism :*

(i): If $\alpha,\beta\in A_n$,then $\alpha\beta\in A_n$,moreover, $\varphi(\alpha\beta)=\alpha\beta=\varphi(\alpha)\varphi(\beta)$

(ii): If $\alpha,\beta\in S_n - A_n$,then $\alpha\beta\in A_n$,moreover, $$\varphi(\alpha\beta)=\alpha\beta(n+1\;n+2)^2=\alpha (n+1\;n+2)\beta(n+1\;n+2)=\varphi(\alpha)\varphi(\beta)$$

(iii): If $\alpha\in S_n-A_n\, ,\beta\in A_n$,then $\alpha\beta\in S_n-A_n$,moreover,
 $$\varphi(\alpha\beta)=\alpha\beta(n+1\;n+2)=\alpha(n+1\;n+2)\beta=\varphi(\alpha)\varphi(\beta)$$

(iv): it is just like the case (iii)

*$\varphi$ is monomorphism:*

Clearly, $(\,e_{S_n}\,)\subseteq \ker\varphi$

Now, let $\pi\in S_n$ is not the identity one with $\varphi(\pi)=e_{A_{n+2}}\,\,\,.$ Then either $\pi\in A_n$ or $\pi\in S_n-A_n.$

If $\pi\in A_n$ then $\pi=\varphi(\pi)=e_{A_{n+2}}=e_{S_{n}}$ ,a contradiction.

If $\pi\in S_n-A_n$ then $\pi(n+1\;n+2)=\varphi(\pi)=e_{A_{n+2}}\,\,$ this implies that $\pi=(n+1\;n+2)\not\in S_n,$ a contradiction.

Then $\ker\varphi=(e_{S_n})$

I wrote this proof explicitly, in other words, I checked everything in this problem we needed. So I think there is a quite some  difference with the three answers.

Comment: This is fine: $G\hookrightarrow S_n\hookrightarrow A_{n+2}$. There are more ways to prove your exercise, e.g., see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27132/embedding-of-finite-groups). Or see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387296/every-finite-group-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-a-n?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Another way is to embed $S_n$ in $A_{2n}$ by mapping $\sigma\in S_n$ to the permutation acting as $\sigma$ on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and that acting as $\sigma$ on $\{n+1,\ldots,2n\}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding of finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27132/embedding-of-finite-groups)

Comment: I'm reluctant to consider this a duplicate because it asks for proof-verification, and the proposed duplicate had no such detailed provision.