# Subgroup of permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Every finite group is a subgroup of An for n>=1
Can anyone give a sketch of the proof. I cannot proceed!

Comment: You probably mean $\mathcal S_n$ and not $\mathcal A_n$. Right?

Comment: Have you already proven the statement that every finite group is a subgroup of $S_n$?  That is known as Cayley's theorem.  If you have there's a trick that you can use to jump to $A_m$ for a larger value of $m$.

Comment: For some tricks concerning "jump to $A_m$", see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547849/any-finite-group-is-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-of-a-n-for-some-positive-integer?noredirect=1&lq=1).